# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException when add jersy json to pom.xml

Tags: java, json, jersey

When I try to add support for jersey json get exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [InjectionManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.CommonScopeProvider(Configuration, InjectionManager)]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
.....
```

I try with jersey-json and jersey-media-moxy.

When I remove that from pom.xml everything works.

**EDIT:**
Fixed when add jersey-hk2

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
          <version>2.25.1</version>
      </dependency>
```